# carrierwave multipart encoding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, multipartform-data

I'm having trouble uploading an image using carrierwave in RoR. Whenever I try to upload a file I get this error:

`You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed. If this is a file upload, please check that your upload form is multipart encoded.`

users#edit:

```
= form_for(@user, multipart: true) do |f|
  =f.file_field :avatar
  = f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"
```

users_controller:

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    if params[:user][:avatar]
      @user.avatar = params[:user][:avatar].tempfile.path
      @user.save!
    end
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

And I have `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader` in user.rb

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign a string in avatar field in your controller so it was throwing error.

The controller code shoudl be

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
     ...
          @user.avatar = params[:user][:avatar]
          @user.save!
       end
    ...
  end
```

so it should be  `@user.avatar = params[:user][:avatar]` not the file path which is string